# Unable to Download Source Code from Azure Bot Service

Tags: azure, botframework

I have recently encountered a bug on the Azure Bot Service which concerns the ability to download the bot's source code to one's local computer so as edit and then push to source control.

When I investigated further, I came to realize that the download link on the bot service blade actually points to https://dev.botframework.com/# rather than a zipped file of the code-base.

Below is the screenshot. Any ideas on how to notify the Bot Service team of this?

[Azure Bot Service Code Download link not valid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Vv7z.png)

Comment: We're not [Azure Support](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/options/), please contact them there.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the link and yes, I am aware you are not Azure Support :)

Answer (score 4):

It's likely taking a long time because it's including the node_modules folder, it should work though, I just tried and after a while I got the zip. We'll look into possibly remove the node modules.

In the meantime, you can get the same files by downloading the content of the wwwroot folder from kudu.
Just visit http://your-bot-name.scm.azurewebsites.net and select PowerShell from the Debug Console menu on the top. Then Click on the site folder and then download the wwwroot folder. The content of wwwroot is exactly what you'd find in the zip you download from the Azure Bot Service.
[image]

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

The download link does actually function (even though the href is pointing to https://dev.botframework.com/# )  You just need to give it some time, for node bots in particular.  The entire node_modules folder is currently being compressed.

You should see some dots on the bottom of the page after clicking the download link:

[image]

I'll send a note to the developers (there should be more visible feedback while the compression is occurring).

Comment: Thanks for the tip Eric. I have waited a while and the link still doesn't function. I also don't think the dots were relevant to the compression of the project files. I'll raise an Azure support ticket and hopefully it's fixed soon